# NodeJS Express: how to get object item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, validation

I try to create a simple login form and fail to validate the password from the MongoDB.

First I create the .post route for the form validation and then I get the MongoDB data which I want to compare with the form.

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  const reqUser = req.body.params.name
  const reqPW = req.body.params.password

  // connect to mongoDB
  const collection = client.db().collection("users")
  collection.find({name: reqUser}).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.send([])
      return
    }
    else {
      console.log('RESULT', results) // returns the object
      console.log('RES PW', results.password) // returns undefined

      // this does not work
      Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log('key is: ', key); // returns 0
      });

      // validate user+pw
      if (!reqUser || !reqPW/*|| reqPW !== password*/) {
        return res.status(401).end()
      }

      // send result to frontend
      res.send(results)
      res.end
    }
  })
})
```

So, I get my object returned in `results` but I cannot get the data from the object.
I also tried to convert it to an array with `Array.from()` but that didn't work either.

Please note that I did not yet implement hashing and salting the passwords yet, as I thought I want a working validation first. Do I need to implement those first?

Comment: Can you post the results object?

Comment: I cannot copy from powershell, but it returns this:  `[{_id: 123456, name: 'username', password: 'yourpassword'}]` (plus some more data which is not important for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/):

> The toArray() method returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all the documents into RAM and exhausting the cursor.

So `toArray()` will return a **array**, not object, therefore your results will be an array containing all the items(object) you get from the db. If you `console.log(results)`, it should print an array rather than object.

Assuming there won't be two users have the same name, the results you get will be just an array containing one object, so you can just do:

```js
results[0].password // get the first object's password field
```

Not sure if this slove your question, but based on your code thats the problem i found in it.

Comment: ooooh, I was confused in my debbuging process as I first mistakenly debugged res[0] instead of results[0] and thought the array was empty.... Now everything makes sense again :)